# How can I make my keyboard more responsive?

Tags: keyboard

I've recently switched from my iPhone 3GS to this HTC Evo Design 4G (4.0.3) because I get free service on the latter phone, and my setup is coming together nicely for the most part, but I have one huge stumbling block: the keyboard.

I've used iOS for ~6 years and I figured the new keyboard would take some getting used to, but I just can't type quickly on any Android keyboard I've tried (stock, Google Keyboard, Perfect Keyboard, etc) because it physically won't let me. It's unable to handle inputs in quick succession. To test this, I tried typing 'a' and 'h' alternating very quickly on each device. On the iPhone the result is "ahahahahahahahahahahaha", but on my Evo it's "ahhhhhhhhhahhhhhh". Elsewhere, input on the device is fairly snappy.

Any suggestions? I've tried Googling the issue with no luck. I type quite a bit and it's driving me nuts that I have to slow down for it to recognize all my inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking this on a Samsung Galaxy S 3, a Nexus 7, and a Nexus 10, with several different keyboard apps, I couldn't see a similar issue, so I suspect this problem is specific to that model of phone. Perhaps HTC skimped on the touchscreen for this device, or did a poor job with the touchscreen integration. If that's it, there's probably nothing you can do but hope that a software update will fix the problem.

Alternatively, it could be a problem with that particular phone. Try giving the touchscreen a wipe with a damp cloth. Try to get access to another phone of the same model and check if it has the same problem: if it is only your phone, you should take it back to the shop and have them fix it.

Comment: This is the only Android device I own so thanks for testing on other devices. I downloaded a touch-test app and experienced it there as well, and I'm starting to think it may just be interpreting my quick touches as drags, similar to [the issue this fellow was having](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229224/android-will-treat-fast-single-touch-as-move). Bummer!